# admin module css is not working in prestashop 1.6

Tags: css, module, controller, prestashop

The admin tab for ([www.mkehome.com](http://www.mkehome.com)) module `css` is not working. When I click on **MODULES**, I get no css with result page. The controller is not calling the css for admin module UI. When I go to update from the list of updates needed, I still get no css with result page.

I have all the other UI's are working just fine.

The Hover over (JS) on `topmenublock` on `homepage` also stop working.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 5):

what hoook do you use in backend for add CSS file?

Note:

```
public function install() {
    if (!parent::install() OR
            !$this->registerHook('displayHeader') OR
            !$this->registerHook('displayBackOfficeHeader') ....


 /**
 * use this for Frontend
 */
public function hookDisplayHeader() {
    $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path) . 'css/styles.css', 'all');
}

/**
 * use this for Backoffice
 */
public function hookDisplayBackOfficeHeader() {
    $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path) . 'css/admin-styles.css', 'all');

    $this->context->controller->addJS(array(
        _PS_JS_DIR_ . 'fileuploader.js',
    ));
}
```

Regards

Comment: Hi,
I had to re-install the module to load the hook again.